# How to allow cyrillic in my package

Tags: r, utf-8, devtools

I am working on a package that includes an object that contains some text in cyrillic. Besides that, the package conforms to UTF-8.
Unfortunately, the cyrillic causes `devtools::check` to fail with:

```
> checking data for non-ASCII characters ... NOTE   Error in iconv(x,
> ...) : 
>     embedded nul in string: 'P\024Q\vQ\0P:P0 P2 P<P0Q\002Q\aP5 (P;Q\016P1P0Q\017 P4Q\vQ\0P:P0 P1P>P;P5P5 1 Q\001P5P:) (P=Q\003P6P=P>
> Q\003P:P0P7P0Q\002Q\f P4P;P8Q\002P5P;Q\fP=P>Q\001Q\002Q\f)'   Calls:
> <Anonymous> ... format.check_package_datasets -> paste0 -> iconv0 ->
> paste0 -> iconv   Execution halted
```

This is solved when I remove the cyrillic text, but that text is actually needed.
I have tried to adapt the DESCRIPTION file to allow UTF-8 next to "russian", but that gives an error message of its own.

How can I allow "russian" next to "UTF-8" in a package, without it failing `devtools::check`?

Comment: You can Unicode escape it, but then it only renders if it runs (and the glyphs are available).

Comment: @alistaire what does that mean? Add "\\" in front of the text?

Comment: Instead of `"Привет"`, use `"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442"`, which you can get with `stringi::stri_escape_unicode` (`\\` escaped an extra time so it doesn't reparse when printed, though for storage that may be undesirable).